# How to sum networkdays for multiple calendars for multiple people

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using MS Excel 2010. What do I need to do to be able to create a table like this:

```
+----------------+--------+-----------------+
| Milestone Date | Team   | Hours Remaining |
+----------------+--------+-----------------+
| 5/27/2016      | Team A | ???             |
+----------------+--------+-----------------+
```

Such that I can enter an arbitrary "Milestone Date" and select a team and calculate "Hours Remaining" like:

```
sum for each person on Team A NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(), Milestone Date, Person X Holiday Calendar + Person X Vacation Calendar) * 8 hrs/day
```

I have a set of tables that look like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| Team Member | Team   | Holiday Calendar |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Person 1    | Team A | Calendar A       |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Person 2    | Team A | Calendar A       |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Person 3    | Team B | Calendar A       |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Person 4    | Team B | Calendar B       |
+-----------------------------------------+

+------------+------------+
| Calendar A | Calendar B |
+------------+------------+
| 5/30/2016  | 9/1/2016   |
+------------+------------+
| 5/31/2016  | 10/1/2016  |
+------------+------------+
| 12/24/2016 | 11/1/2016  |
+------------+------------+

+---------------------------------------------------+
|                 Vacation Calendar                 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  Person 1  |  Person 2  |  Person 3  |  Person 4  |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  5/13/2016 |  5/02/2016 |  5/22/2016 |  4/27/2016 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  5/13/2016 |            |  6/3/2016  |            |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

For, example, is there a way to wrap NETWORKDAYS() is some kind of `FOR_EACH(team member on Team A)` construct? Is there some notation to combine the vacation calendar of person A with the holiday calendar of team A?

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm not looking for a script. I'm looking for how to use excel formulas like NETWORKDAYS() to operate on a matrix of values. Specifically, I'm looking for suggestions on how to implement this algorithm: `sum for each person on Team A NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(), Milestone Date, Person X Holiday Calendar + Person X Vacation Calendar) * 8 hrs/day`

Comment: What have you tried so far? [NETWORKDAYS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7)

Comment: So far, I've tried reading the online help for excel functions looking for ways to get functions like `NETWORKDAYS` to operate on the type of dataset I have. I've come up empty, so I've come here to ask how it's done.

Comment: Your question is about an entire solution of a complex problem, which likely require macros to some.  As such is off topic here being too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. 
First, I extended the "Team Member" table to include the hours per team member.

```
+-----------------------------------------+--------------+
| Team Member | Team   | Holiday Calendar | Hours Remain |
+-------------+--------+------------------+--------------+
| Person 1    | Team A | Calendar A       |  FORMULA     |
+-------------+--------+------------------+--------------+
| Person 2    | Team A | Calendar A       |  FORMULA     |
+-------------+--------+------------------+--------------+
| Person 3    | Team B | Calendar A       |  FORMULA     |
+-------------+--------+------------------+--------------+
| Person 4    | Team B | Calendar B       |  FORMULA     |
+-------------+--------+------------------+--------------+
```

The formula is

```
=NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(),Milestone Date,ArrayFormula({HLOOKUP(Which Holiday Calendar,Holidays!$A:$F,ROW(Holidays!$A$2:$A$100),0),HLOOKUP(Which Vacation Calendar,Vacation!$A:$F,ROW(Vacation!$A$2:$A$100),0)}))
```

Where the key is the CSE formula to get an array of dates and the {} to join two arrays. (I posted this orignally for Excel, but ended up using Google Sheets. So, the syntax is slightly different. But, Excel probably has a way of getting a similar effect.)

Then in the final table, just the Hours Remaining is just a SUMIF(the hours remaining for Team A)